# regular expression to get string value in python

Tags: python, regex

I would like to get a string value from the given string using Regular Expression

Regular Expression:

```
(?i)\|HUMAN=(.?)|\|HUMAN=(.?)\|
```

String Value:

> this is test results|HUMAN=Man|HM_LA=this is test results

I would like to get 'Man' as results. I have tried enough but not successful, can someone help please?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match any text after `HUMAN=` and before `|`, you could do:

```
import re
res = re.search(r'\|HUMAN=(\w+?)\|', 'this is test results|HUMAN=Man|HM_LA=this is test results')
print(res.group(1))
```

**Output**

```
Man
```

If you want to match only *words*, do:

```
res = re.search(r'\|HUMAN=(\w+?)\|', 'this is test results|HUMAN=Man|HM_LA=this is test results')
print(res.group(1))
```

**Output**

```
Man
```

The `\w` matches Unicode word characters and the `+`  means one or more times. See [here](https://regex101.com/r/sggFSM/1) for a detailed explanation of the last regex, and [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) for an introduction to regular expressions in Python.